# How to resolve 'unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested' error?

Tags: javascript, json, oracle, plsql, client-server

I am trying to pass a large number of records as a stringify object from client to the server. In the server side there is a function called 'Get_Records' to capture that string object. Then it should parse the string object into records back and do necessary modifications. This is the way of calling the stringify function from client side.

```
stringify(rec, "IS_TRANSACTION=${IsTransaction}^COMPANY_ID=${CompanyId}^PR_TRANSACTION_SEQ=${PrTransactionSeq}^SPRICE=${SPrice}^SQUANTITY=${SQuantity}^", JSON) into SelectionVar;

call Get_Records(SelectionVar) into invoiceExist;
```

Below is the server side function to capture the string object.

```
FUNCTION Get_Records(
   selection_string_  IN VARCHAR2 )  RETURN VARCHAR2
IS 
   records_               json_array := 
   json_array.parse(selection_string_);
   current_selection_     VARCHAR2(32000);
BEGIN
   //Code
END;
```

But when I try to pass the string object for a large number of records from the stringify() function, it is not captured by the server side function 'Get_Records'. It gives an error called, 'unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested, details: undefined undefined'. I tried using the 'CLOB' datatype for the server side function. But it is also not working for a very large number of records. Is there a proper way to pass the string object retrieved from the stringify function to the server side. ?

Answer (score 0):

Intercept the length of the string to make it less than 1000. Or store it in a file and upload it

Answer (score 0):

Prior to Oracle version 19c, JSON functionality is a bit limited. Which version are you working with?